# how to change the iconsize in the navigation view using design support library?

Tags: android

i am using navigation view using design support library i have 7 menu items with icon to each item. i want to adjust the size of the icon of the menuitem. is there a way to change the Icon size of the navigation view either through xml or in java ??
drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/Home"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/home3"
            android:title="@string/inbox_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/Cards"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/card"
            android:title="@string/draft_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/Account"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/user11"
            android:title="@string/starred_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/Credits"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/earn"
            android:title="@string/sent_mail_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/Logout"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/exit"
            android:title="@string/spam_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/subheader"
            android:title="Help Us"
            >
            <menu>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/Support"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:icon="@drawable/support"
                    android:title="@string/all_mail_string"
                    />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/Feedback"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:icon="@drawable/feedback"
                    android:title="@string/trash_string" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_2"
                    android:icon="@drawable/star"
                    android:title="@string/navigation_item_2"/>
            </menu>
        </item>


    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google noticed that the apps that were using the navigation drawer in wrong way. If you read [this](https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) post by google designers they strictly ask you to follow a particular set of text sizes, paddings, margins etc. which they do not want you to go against. Thats why they came up with the Navigation view in the support library which has all kinds of typography, key lines and margins and the vertical spacing pre-defined. I recommend not to go against their design guidelines.